# If I have multiple open tabs how do I merge them into single split tab?

Tags: conemu

I can split a single tab, but how do I gather several already open tabs (or windows) into a single split tab/window?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's impossible yet. [Splits](http://conemu.github.io/en/SplitScreen.html) may be created either with creating new [RealConsole](http://conemu.github.io/en/RealConsole.html) or [recreating of existing one](http://conemu.github.io/en/RestartTab.html). Check docs for more details.

Comment: Is this on the roadmap, by chance?  I love me some ConEmu, but this is the one thing I feel it's missing.

Comment: Sure, it's in roadmap.